# customize jquery countdown layout

Tags: jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

Im stuck with the [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) layout, I want to display something like this:

1 day, hours:minuts:sec

I could chieve it using the `layout:` option like this

```
layout: '{dn} {dl} {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}'
```

but now I got a problem, when the countdown is less than 24hrs it still shows the days like this

0 days, hours:minuts:sec

I need that when the countdown is less than 24hrs do not display the days

I know that can be done with a conditional but I do not know how to check it's less than 24hrs.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supose you have you have several countdowns in the page, each countdown has the data attribute `data-countdown-until` so you can customize the countdowns with something like:

```
$('div[data-countdown-until]').each (index, element) ->
      $element = $(element)
      date = new Date($element.data('countdown-until'))
      $element.countdown(until: date, description: '', onTick: highlightLast5, layout: '{dn} {dl} {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}')
```

in this case it will show `N days hh:mm:ss` 
The above code works for whatever quantity of timers you have in the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add the `onTick: changeLayout` to your options when you initialize the countdown. Then add this `changeLayout()` function to your JS. Like so:

```
var changed = false;
$(selector).countdown({layout: '{dn} {dl} {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}', onTick: changeLayout, until: +10}

function changeLayout(periods)
{
    if(!changed && $.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) <= 86400) //24hr = 24*60*60s
    {
        $(selector).countdown('option', {layout: '{hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}'});
        changed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, so the periods are like the seconds right?

Comment: `periods` is the array of current countdown periods (int[7] - based on the format setting): [0] is years, [1] is months, [2] is weeks, [3] is days, [4] is hours, [5] is minutes, and [6] is seconds.

Comment: your solution does not work very well, I have like 5 countdowns running in the frontpage it only works with 1 countdown, the others are not displayed, chrome shows me this error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @SsouLlesS This was just an example for a single countdown.